# Get and show username from firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to get username from firebase realtime database and show it in label of my TableViewCell. What am i doing wrong? userShortname.text still stays empty. I'm using only email/password auth
Here's my code

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var username: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let profilePath = ref.child("users").child(userID!)
        profilePath.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let snapValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let snapUsername = snapValue?["username"] as? String ?? ""
            self.username = snapUsername
        })

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell

    cell.userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 35.5
    cell.userAvatar.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.userShortname.text = self.username

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Hey @Pselok, please copy the relevant code to the question body (and not as an image link). Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `self.tableView.reloadData()` before exiting your `obserseSingleEvent` closure. For instance:

```
profilePath.obserseSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    ...
    self.username = snapUsername
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

this will let your `tableView` know that the network response has arrived ;)

Comment: thank you very much! i was trying to add it after exiting observeSingleEvent

Answer (score 0):

**1. Firebase calls are async**

This means a separate thread is created to handle its assigned task and the main thread never waits for it to be done before moving on to the next operation.

**2. iOS Main Thread**

All UI updates are done through the main thread. Never run lengthy tasks which take more a fraction of a second to complete on this thread.

Once Firebase has done executing its task, you need to convey this info back to the user hence a UI update is required. Simply writing `self.tableView.reloadData()` will always work **IF** everything's running smoothly with Firebase; even they can't guarantee this :)

In the event the Firebase query gets hanged up:

```
Blocks the main thread
       ----> Deem your app unresponsive
            --> If unresponsive for a couple seconds, the watchdog kills your app.
```

To avoid this, once Firebase's thread is done executing and you've added your new data in memory, you need to tell the main thread to perform any relevant UI updates.

```
profilePath.obserseSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    ...
    self.username = snapUsername

    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I would recommend you familiarize yourself with [iOS multi-threading](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1) and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536176/how-to-do-lengthy-operations-without-being-killed-by-the-watchdog-iphone) answer for lengthy task operations.

Comment: You're welcomed mate. Consider marking one of the two responses as your final answer and up voting in order to close your question. Happy coding! :)

Comment: By the way, Firebase *completion blocks* are always called on the main queue so you don't need to wrap those calls in `DispatchQueue.main` at all ;)